# How to hide all child elements except first child element using CSS

Tags: css

I have a table which is looping dynamically. Now I need to hide all `<tr>` with the class `.dynamic-tr` except 1st table's `<tr class="dynamic-tr">` by using CSS.

```
<table class="dynamic-table">
  <tr class="dynamic-tr">
    <th>Resource Name</th>
    <th>Allocation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>100%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="dynamic-table">
  <tr class="dynamic-tr">
    <th>Resource Name</th>
    <th>Allocation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alex</td>
    <td>50%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="dynamic-table">
  <tr class="dynamic-tr">
    <th>Resource Name</th>
    <th>Allocation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bryce</td>
    <td>100%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried with this CSS but its not working. Can somebody please suggest.

```
.dynamic-table .dynamic-tr {
  display: none;
}
.dynamic-table:first-of-type .dynamic-tr {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: `dynamic-tr-one` did you mean `dynamic-tr` ?

Comment: Why are you using multiple tables each with a single entry?

Comment: Yes @Akshay its `dynamic-tr` I just updated the question

Comment: are there any sibling elements before the table?

Comment: These tables are coming dynamically @DavidsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: No @FabrizioCalderan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not` to achieve what you need.

```css
table.dynamic-table:not(:first-child) .dynamic-tr {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table class="dynamic-table">
  <tr class="dynamic-tr">
    <th>Resource Name</th>
    <th>Allocation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>100%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="dynamic-table">
  <tr class="dynamic-tr">
    <th>Resource Name</th>
    <th>Allocation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alex</td>
    <td>50%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="dynamic-table">
  <tr class="dynamic-tr">
    <th>Resource Name</th>
    <th>Allocation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bryce</td>
    <td>100%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to hide all `.dynamic-tr` except first `.dynamic-tr` in first `.dynamic-table`

Comment: @Sunandha Yes. And that;s what's happening in my answer. No ?

Comment: No, its hiding all `.dynamic-tr`

Comment: @Sunandha As far as i can see the words `Resource Name` and
   `Allocation`  are visible . Which could not be visible if all `dynamic-tr` were hidden. If all `.dynamic-tr` are hidden, where do the `Resource Name Allocation` words come from ?

Comment: I didn't copied it correctly, Its working now. Thanks for your quick solution @Mihai

Comment: @Sunandha glad i could help.Cheers :

Answer (score -1):

Does this satisfy your requirements ?

```
body > table > tbody > tr.dynamic-tr { display: none; }
body > table:first-of-type > tbody > tr.dynamic-tr {display: inline;}
```